# SignalR, Limited unique connections (opened tabs) IIS8, Windows8

Tags: signalr

It is impossible to use SignalR, when several tabs opened  with unique ids assigned to each tab (see. [When SignalR made 8-10 connections at a time live chat doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426163/when-signalr-made-8-10-connections-at-a-time-live-chat-doesnt-work)).

But. there is a workaround I described in this stackoverflow issue. The idea is to overwrite connectionid  in order, that every opened tab would have the same connection id:  thus, logicaly, in my particular case, there is no reason to have unique ids for each tab, 'cos each tab is opened by one MyApplicationUserId.

Anyway, it has been noticed in stackoverflow (see [SignalR How is a duplicate Connection Id handled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522090/signalr-how-is-a-duplicate-connection-id-handled) ), that connectionid must be unique. And they say, that IConnectionIdGenerator  will be removed in an upcomming release.

So, this is a kind of blind alley. I must use unique ids, but I cannot use SignalR with several browser tabs opened.

Thank you.
Dmitry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As has been discussed in the SignalR issue you've opened [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/849), most modern browsers limit the maximum number of concurrent connections (typically around 6) to the same site.

One workaround is to use subdomains, i.e. each tab connects to a different subdomain (this is the approach Facebook is using). Another option would be to start just one connection and use `localStorage` as a message bus between tabs as suggested by FreshCode in this question: [SignalR and Browser Connection limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724202/signalr-and-browser-connection-limit)

Comment: Hm.. I created dublicated subdomain in IIS8, thus I have: im.domain.com, im2.domain.com. And I load scripts from im and im2 subdomains,  and open connecion to them, mixing in such way, that 4 chrome tabs opened with loaded scripts from im, and 4 tabs with scripts from im2. and connection.url I set in the same way. But anyway, I cannot make more then 6 tabs work... :(

Comment: Interesting, the two subdomains should be treated separately when counting concurrent connections... Have you tried in another browser and/or watched the network tab to be sure it connects to different subdomains?

Comment: Yes, I used chrome network inspections tool, and 3 tabs get scripts and connections from "im", and 3 tabs from "im2". I will try to figure it out at the weekend.

Comment: When I use my hoster, then it works. When I use my local IIS8, then it doesn't. That means I need to setup my subdomains correctly. Everything works fine now. I feel better :)

Comment: @AlexanderKöplinger , I have a chat application on master page (common for all pages) and i need connection on each page then how can i have open more than 6 tabs. Any Idea would be helpful.

Comment: @G.SBhangal , i also looking for same approach , if you would have find any solution to solve this problem , can u please share it

Comment: @SajjadAliKhan , Hi I have resolved this problem using the multiple subdomains, but keep in mind that all the subdomains should point out to the main domain and randomly load the signal R from the subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

To bypass browser limtation you can use ‛localStorage‛ to communicate between windows and to have only one window as connection owner. Other windows in this case use connection owner to receive/send messages. [IWC-SignalR](https://github.com/slimjack/IWC-SignalR) is an implementation of such approach.

Answer (score 0):

yes. 
You will create dynamic sub-domains for the signal R connections, because there are browser limitation for the concurrent requests [max = 8] and for different browser this concurrent limitation may vary.

For the dynamic sub-domains you need to set DNS for the sub-domains from the hosting panel, so these dynamic sub-domains point to your main domain.
e.g. xyz.com is your main domain, abc1.xyz.com is your sub-domain, abc2.xyz.com is your sub-domain, abc3.xyz.com is your sub-domain, abc4.xyz.com is your sub-domain.
These all sub-domains point to main domain after DNS setting and IIS setting.
This same way works in Chat application.
Good luck...