# SignalR Connections break entire site

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr, messaging, freeze

I'm using SignalR 2.2.2 to send users messages from my backend. When a user is logged in, and if other conditions are met, their connection is added to a group with the user's userId on my message hub.

It works great, as long as they have ~10 or fewer tabs/windows open. Any beyond that, they're stuck in "Loading..." indefinitely.

It seems to just be getting stuck on $.connection.hub.start();

I don't necessarily need to allow each user an infinite amount of signalr connections, but breaking the entire site for them on 10 open tabs is a problem.

OKAY BUT HERE'S THE THING. When I change my project's server setting from Local IIS to IIS Express, this problem vanishes! BUT! When we build the solution & put it on the test server, it's still broken.

What is going on???

I've tried catching or handling an error, but it still just hangs there.

$(function () {

if (loggedInUser != null)
      {

var user = loggedInUser.UserId;
    var messaging = $.connection.messageHub;

```
    if (conditions) {
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                messaging.server.joinGroup(user);
        });
    }
 }
```

});

I can get this to work with IIS Express. Now I need it to work like that on my test (and then later production) Server.

What else can I even try?

Comment: What OS is used by your test server?

Comment: You might be hitting browser limits - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029069/signalr-limited-unique-connections-opened-tabs-iis8-windows8