# SignalR not handling requests after some limit.Tabs remains loading even to other browser on same or different machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

When number of tabs increases on browser for signalR implemented domain.The tab remains spinning after some limit of tabs.

From some reasearch it is said that it is the limitation of browser.The links are:

- https://medium.com/yasser-shaikh/multiple-tab-issue-with-signal-r-9df76c1ffba0
- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2744
- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/849
- [SignalR, Limited unique connections (opened tabs) IIS8, Windows8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029069/signalr-limited-unique-connections-opened-tabs-iis8-windows8)

But when I try to browse any url from same domain from different machine or from different browser, tabs are spinning on them too. the other machine tabs starts working as soon as I closed some tabs of the first browsers.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The links that you have shared already describes the problem and also provided the answers.

For example "Using localstorage as a message bus between the tabs". This should fix the problem. For that purpose you can use the *IWC-SignalR* library from here: https://github.com/slimjack/IWC-SignalR if you want to reduce the work load.
Sample codes are as following:

```
var echoHub = SJ.iwc.SignalR.getHubProxy('echo', {
    client: {
        displayMsg: function (msg) {
          console.log(msg);
        }
    }
});
SJ.iwc.SignalR.start().done(function () {
    console.log('started');
    echoHub.server.send('test').done(function () {
        console.log('sent');
    });
});
```

Here hub `Echo` with method `Send` defined on server. Method Send calls method `displayMsg` of all clients.

Then here is the `displayMsg` method:

```
var echoHub = SJ.iwc.SignalR.getHubProxy('echo', {
    client: {
        displayMsg: function (msg) {
          console.log(msg);
        }
    }
});

echoHub.server.send('test');
```

The full implementation and the description is available on the above mentioned link.

Comment: Ya I have explored the solutions you have mentioned. And appplied it too. Now I am able to open multiple tabs with in my machine. However when I load multiple tabs on mine. It will block all other users on other machines. They will only be able to explore the URLS untill I close tabs on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Ya I have explored the solutions you have mentioned. And appplied it too. Now I am able to open multiple tabs with in my machine. However when I load multiple tabs on mine. It will block all other users on other machines. They will only be able to explore the URLS untill I close tabs on mine. it is blocking the block server when blocked by any user browser