# SignalR multiple concurrent tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am using Signal R for chat application in my web application.i am using chat on my master page and it open like a Facebook chat area. It is working fine but when i open more than 6 tabs in same browser it hangs no other tabs are responding...(waiting for available socket...)

i searched and implemented many things from internet but nothing found.

finally i decided to do this using sub-domain concept.

i have created 3 sub-domains

```
x.abc.com
y.abc.com
z.abc.com
```

now should i have to host my application on the above sub domains or have to do anything else with this?

Comment: See if this answer is relevant for you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426163/when-signalr-made-8-10-connections-at-a-time-live-chat-doesnt-work

Comment: @Jens their is no any solution provided on specified link which can help me.

Comment: You are hitting the limit of concurrent connections for you browser - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: @Sukhbir - I think Jens is right. It's the first point in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426163/when-signalr-made-8-10-connections-at-a-time-live-chat-doesnt-work#10438102 - specifically on your development machine you can only have 5 or so simultaneous SignalR connections. It will be fine on Windows Server